# Swift: UIViewController doesn't auto deiniting

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, dealloc, deinit

I added to my UIViewController the code below:

```
deinit {
    print("DEINIT")
}
```

And then i used the code below:

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
            let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newViewController") as! MultiGameView

            self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

But the deinit of the view controller didn't happen, what am i missing here?

My problem is that after i go back to the main viewcontroller, and then again to newViewController, the newViewController hasn't been deinit so his properties stay as they were and his variables too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your viewcontroller simply does not get deinitialized at that point. your new viewcontroller gets presented "on top of it".

Comment: Is there any way for me to present a new view controller but not ontop of a one?

Comment: tell me about your app. is the viewcontroller you posted the code from your rootviewcontroller?

Comment: i'm confused. in which viewcontroller did you implement the `deinit`?

Comment: i tried to simplify it for the question, but i added the deinit to the newviewcontroller. i started at the main, moved to the new, moved again to the main, and then again to the new and the second time i got to new i noticed that all of the "garbage" from the first time the new appeared stayed.

Comment: can you show me what happens in the second viewcontroller?